# Laravel handling exception

Tags: php, exception, error-handling, laravel, namespaces

I'm just jump into laravel, this is my first project with.

Now i'm trying to add new exception to handler stack, but for sorry it's not working and i don't know why.

here is my exception class

```
namespace Lib\Modules\Users\Exceptions;

use Lib\Abstracts\AbstractException;

class ConnotCreateUserException extends AbstractException {

}
```

Here is my abstract

```
namespace Lib\Abstracts;

class AbstractException extends \Exception {

}
```

and here is my error registration inside app/start/global.php

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});

App::error(function(Lib\Modules\Users\Exceptions\ConnotCreateUserException $exception){
   return 'Sorry! Something is wrong with this account!';
});
```

when i throw the exception, i got blank page. but i'm sure it's handled as type of "\Exception" exception.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

As the code looked fine, I just did some tests with it and it works for me, just make sure your namespaces are being loaded correctly by doing:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

But, anyway, here's what I did:

1) Created a PSR-4 autoloading for it:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        ...
    ],
    "psr-4": {
        "Lib\\" : "app/App/Lib"
    }
},
```

2) Create the files using your very content:

```
app/App/Lib/Abstracts/AbstractException.php
app/App/Lib/Modules/Users/Exceptions/ConnotCreateUserException.php
```

3) executed

```
composer dump-autoload
```

4) opened `vendor/composer/autoload_psr4.php` just to make sure it was there:

```
return array(
    'Lib\\' => array($baseDir . '/app/App/Lib'),
);
```

5) Added this all in my `routes.php` file:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);
});

App::error(function(Lib\Modules\Users\Exceptions\ConnotCreateUserException $exception){
   return 'Sorry! Something is wrong with this account!';
});

Route::get('/', function()
{
    throw new Lib\Modules\Users\Exceptions\ConnotCreateUserException("We should not get this message!", 1);
});
```

6) Hit:

```
http://server.dev/
```

And got the message

```
Sorry! Something is wrong with this account!
```

Comment: i don't why it's not working for me! however, i don't use psr-4 but psr-0 instead. do you think this have a relation to my problem? my exception file located in: app/Lib/Modules/Users/Exceptions/ConnotCreateUserException.php and my composer.json autoload is: "psr-0": { "Lib": "app" }. all other classes working fine but this exception. i tried to dump-autoload form composer but same results.

Comment: PSR-0 or 4, doesn't matter, but you're not showin all of your code, so it's hard to say. How are you raising that exception? Try to add a root slash (\) to the namespaced class, like: `\Lib\Modules\Users\Exceptions\ConnotCreateUserException`, sometimes it's just a namespace conflict and it happens a lot in exception handling.

Comment: i had install a fresh version of laravel and move all old files to it. and guess what! it's worked. however, currently i don't have enough time to dig deep in this issue, but i will when i have time. i will not let it go in peace.